# Updating size of fancybox with iFrame content everytime the content changes

Tags: jquery, iframe, resize, fancybox, postmessage

I'm using fancybox 1.3.1. Now I load an iFrame into the Fancybox which works fine. In the iFrame the user goes from step to step. At some step the height of the content changes. How can I update the height of the iFrame?

I tried jQuery postMessage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fileadmin/templates/lib/jquery.ba-postmessage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#fancylink").fancybox({
        'type'    :    'iframe',
        'width' : 700,
        'height' : 450,
        'autoScale' : false
    }); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// set inital height
var if_height = 450;

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.receiveMessage){
        $.receiveMessage(function(e){  

            // Get the height from the passsed data.
            var h = Number( e.data.replace( /.*if_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ));
            if ( !isNaN( h ) && h > 0 && h !== if_height ) {
                // Height has changed, update the iframe.
                // checking min and max height
                h=(h<450)?450:h; 
                $("#fancybox-frame").height( if_height = h );
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I get two height styles with overflow:hidden; as can be seen here:

```
<div id="fancybox-inner" style="top: 10px; left: 10px; width: 700px; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe id="fancybox-frame" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" src="https://www.externaldomain.com#http://www.internaldomain.com/page" hspace="0" name="fancybox-frame1347984635401" style="height: 1180px;">
```

As result there is more content available but the user cannot scroll. So doing nothing is better than this.

I also tried it with

```
$('#element').fancybox({
    'onComplete' : function(){
        $.fancybox.resize();
    }
});
```

but here nothing happens (no resize). I think this resize is only at the first load of the fancybox. But also on the first time nothing happens.

Is there a solution to my problem or can I only use a fixed size?

**Solution:**

So I added the following code and it seems to work as desired:

```
$("#fancybox-inner").height( h );
$("#fancybox-wrap").height( h+20 );
$.fancybox.center();
```

I will test a little bit, but I think this can work. What happens if the fancybox is higher than the current page? Will the page increase in size?

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like below.

```
 function updateMyFancyBox() {
    $.fancybox.wrap.height($.fancybox.inner.height() + $('div#yourContentDiv').height());//increase fancybox height by adding your div height.
    $.fancybox.update();//Fancybox will re-size according to new size, if it exceeds size limit, it will show scroll bar.
 }
```